# Is adding a derived type an interface breaking change?

Tags: ada

On page 324 of 'Programming in Ada 2012' by John Barnes, he states that a tag indeterminate call will compile if there is only one type that defines the primitives involved. So, given:

`root.ads:`

```
package root is

   type object is tagged null record;

   function is_further (X, Y: Object) return boolean;
   function unit return object;

   -- type circle is new object with null record;

end root;
```

The call `is_further(unit, unit)` will compile. However, if we later add a derived type such as circle to that interface, the call will be ambiguous:

```
main.adb:8:14: ambiguous expression (cannot resolve "is_further")
main.adb:8:14: possible interpretation (inherited) at other.ads:4
main.adb:8:14: possible interpretation at root.ads:5
main.adb:8:25: ambiguous call to "unit"
main.adb:8:25: interpretation at other.ads:4
main.adb:8:25: interpretation at root.ads:6
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

As far as I know, that makes Ada the only programming language where adding a derived type is an interface breaking change. Since that's a horrible prospect, is there any way to force the given expression to always fail, even with only one type?

A clunky solution is to define a derived type that isn't used, for every leaf (sub)type that I expose. I can't even make it private to forbid usage by clients, but I won't later extend that type, so at least the original problem won't arise.

Note that the problem isn't just there for the root type. It's a problem for all leaf types (i.e. without any type derived from it). For example, if we later extend object in another package:

```
with root; use root;

package circles is

   type round_thing is new object with null record;

   procedure turn_around( R : round_thing );

   type ambiguate_indeterminate_calls_for_round_thing is new round_thing with null record;

end circles;
```

I actually wanted to just define round_thing, and leave the option to later add an oval. But without the unused derived type, someone might have written `turn_around(unit)` in the meantime, so when I add my oval type, they will be faced with `ambiguous expression (cannot resolve "turn_around")`.

It seems to me a flaw in Ada that tag indeterminate calls are allowed, so is there any good way to disallow them, either by changing the code in the package or by adding a compiler flag?

Comment: It's not so much that adding the subtype is a problem, it's that in combination with having a primitive operation that returns the base type.  Ada will generate an override to unit for the new subtype.  Now your calls to unit are ambiguous unless you use a qualified expression:  is_further(Object'(unit), unit).  That gives the compiler enough enough info to know which unit to call for both parameters.  You should be using child packages (root.circles) for expanding your API.  Then the compiler will force you to specify which unit you are using.

Comment: even with child packages, if there is a client somewhere that did `use root; use root.circles;` and then calls `turn_around(unit)` it will work until I add an oval to root.circles. So I gather you are saying just accept that it is a breaking change, and if i want to add oval, do that in a new child package?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn The idea is to have only one tagged type per package, you'll find this in the [style guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Style_Guide). One suggested naming convention is to name the main tagged type `Instance` (Rosen 95) so that the package name carries the intent of the type (i.e. `Circle.Instance`).

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn If someone does both use root and use root.circles, then you are in the same situation for any language where you expose two symbols or identifiers with the same name.  It would be analogous in C++ to doing using namespace std and using namespace my_space where both have an object called cout.  It would cause ambiguities.  In any language you have to decide how to handle that.  The important part here is that the child package in Ada doesn't break the API of the root package.  Anyone using just the package Root will be unaffected when you add Root.Circles later on

Comment: As a matter of terminology, `circle` isn’t a subtype, it’s a derived type. If it has been a subtype (`subtype circle is object`) you wouldn’t have seen this problem - of course, you wouldn’t have an approach to your problem of supporting both circles and ovals either. The Wikibook has a brief (& not that helpful) [discussion](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Basic#Type_and_subtype) of this.